# Check for equality only among truthy values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logic, underscore.js, logical-operators

I have two lists of contacts:

```
Old List:
[{ firstname: "James", nickname: "Jim" }];

New List:
[
  { firstname: "Jim" },
  { firstname: "Jane" }
];
```

I would like to create a test to compare each new contact to the existing old contact to see if there is a match. Contacts should be considered equal if either the firstname or nickname match (so the new contact with firstname "Jim" should match with the old contact with the nickname "Jim", but not "Jane").

My first attempt was pretty lame:

```
let equalFirst = (
  ( old.firstname === new.firstname ) ||
  ( old.nickname === new.nickname ) ||
  ( old.firstname === new.nickname ) ||
  ( old.nickname === new.firstname )
) ? true : false;
```

In addition to not being elegant, this returns an incorrect equality. If the nickname is `undefined` for both contacts, then JavaScript considers them equal.

How can I check for equality only if the values being tested are truthy? Using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), I get to something that returns the correct equality:

```
let oldNames = _.compact([ old.firstName, old.nickname ]),
    newNames = _.compact([ new.firstName, new.nickname ]),
    isMatch  = _.some( oldNames, ( item ) => {
                 return _.contains( newNames, item );
               });
```

However, I feel like there's probably a better way of performing this operation so that `undefined` values are excluded and only truthy values are evaluated for equality.

Answer (score 0):

Add truthly validation.

```
let equalFirst = (
  ( new.firstname && old.firstname === new.firstname ) ||
  ( new.nickname && old.nickname === new.nickname ) ||
  ( new.nickname && old.firstname === new.nickname ) ||
  ( new.firstname && old.nickname === new.firstname )
) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a set of all names and check the set for the result.

```js
var oldList = [{ firstname: "James", nickname: "Jim" }],
    newList = [{ firstname: "Jim" }, { firstname: "Jane" }],
    oldSet = new Set(
        oldList
            .reduce((r, { firstname, nickname }) => r.concat(firstname, nickname), [])
            .filter(Boolean) // removes undefined or empty names
    ),
    result = newList.map(
        ({ firstname, nickname }) => [firstname, nickname].some(v => oldSet.has(v))
    );

console.log(result);
console.log([...oldSet]);
```